# Specify multiple nested random effects in lme with heteroskedastic variance across group

Tags: r, nlme, random-effects

I want to fit a random effects model with two separate nested random effects. I can easily do this using the `lmer` package in R. Here's how:

```
model<-lmer(y ~ 1 + x + (1 | oid/gid) + (1 | did/gid), data=data)
```

Here, I'm fitting a random intercept for `oid` nested within `gid` and `did` nested within `gid`. This works well. However, I want to fit a model where the variance of the intercept changes with the `gid` for both the random effects. `nlme` package is capable of doing that. However, it's not clear how. The best I could do is like so:

```
model <- lme(y ~ 1 + x, random=list(gid=~1, oid=~1, did=~1), weights=varIdent(form=~1|gid), data = data)
```

but this nests the `did` within `oid` and `gid` nested together. I tried to use the idea from a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme), which seems like a close problem but the answer has not been explained well in that question. I hope someone can figure this out.